# ZeroMQ Java example hangs on Ubuntu 12

Tags: ubuntu, zeromq, ubuntu-12.10, jzmq

I'm trying to program with ZeroMQ on Ubuntu using the Java examples. I've successfully built ZeroMq core and Java bindings, but trying to run simple example, it just hangs indefinitely.

Here's what I've done so far, btw, I'm using `JDK/JRE 1.7`, `ZeroMQ 3.2.2`, and `Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit`

**Build ZeroMQ Core Libraries**

I downloaded core ZeroMQ 3.2.2 POSIX tarball from [here](http://download.zeromq.org/zeromq-3.2.2.tar.gz), extracted and built according to instructions [here](http://www.zeromq.org/area%3adownload). Configure, make, and installation all went well, no errors, I also ran `ldconfig` following `make` to update the system library cache. A quick look at `/usr/local/lib` and the core libraries appear to have built correctly...

```
usr1@ubuntu:/usr/local/lib$ ls -ltr *.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root dev 15 Apr  1 19:31 libzmq.so -> libzmq.so.3.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root dev 16 Apr  1 20:14 libjzmq.so -> libjzmq.so.0.0.0
```

**Build JZMQ Java Bindings**

Downloaded Java bindings source from [here](http://github.com/zeromq/jzmq), configured, ran make; all looks good. This creates `zmq.jar` and `zmq-perf.jar`; ran `ldconfig` again to update library cache; moved jars to `/usr/local/share/java`...

```
usr1@ubuntu:/usr/local/share/java$ ls -ltr
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr1 usr1 40507 Apr  1 20:14 zmq.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 usr1 usr1  4809 Apr  2 08:41 zmq-perf.jar
```

**Running Example `local_lat`**

I ran the `local_lat` example detailed [here](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3ajava) using the following settings for my environment...

```
java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib -classpath /usr/local/share/java/zmq-perf.jar:/usr/local/share/java/zmq.jar local_lat tcp://127.0.0.1:5555 1 100
```

Got `UnsatisfiedLinkError`; fixed that by just logging in and out.
Ran again and it just hangs, no errors, nata, zilch. I removed the argument `100` from above and got the usage message from `local_lat`, so I know it's finding the zmq jar files since `local_lat` class resides in `zmq-perf.jar`. Ran again with the above command, and it just hangs; no errors, nothing. A bit of a let down since it was quite a bit of work to get everything built.

**UPDATE**

See below, turns out this was a problem with how I was testing

Comment: You may wish to start out with the native Java implementation [JeroMQ](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq)

Comment: @Steve-o Is that a pure Java implementation? Will it work standlone without any dependencies to `so` or `dll` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out everything I did was correct. The core libs and Java bindings were built and installed successfully, the problem was the example...

```
java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib -classpath /usr/local/share/java/zmq-perf.jar:/usr/local/share/java/zmq.jar local_lat tcp://127.0.0.1:5555 1 100
```

The `local_lat` program is not a Hello World test, I thought it was, it's a bit misleading on the [jzmq](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3ajava) site, the above is a command line example, not an example to test the installation, and that was confirmed by looking at the code for `local_lat`; it doesn't do anything, and certainly does not output anything which is why it appeared to just hang.

I tested ZeroMq with this [code](http://zguide.zeromq.org/java%3aasyncsrv), downloaded and javac'ed it, used the above command to run it.